# Jsoup not working in android even after implementing in seperate thread

Tags: java, android, jsoup

#### Activity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("ERR", "entered into oncreate");
    Thread t=new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                String url="https://www.google.co.in/gfe_rd=cr&ei=ySm0U9fCNY7V8gec7oGwAw&gws_rd=ssl";
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                    Log.d("ERR", "connected jsoup");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }});
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Application closes unexpectedly. I have been trying all the method i found in internet including async task,it just end up in **"application closes unexpectedly"**

#### manifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testing"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testing.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >     
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.testing.DetailedActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

On other method i used AsyncTask method for which code is below.

```
 public class Jsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.d("ERR", "entered into pre-execute");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    ProgressDialog progress;

    }
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    
    Log.d("ERR", "entered into do-in-background");



    String url="https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwjWHVIIojsMWHRlYXpza3FFYm8&usp=sharing";
    try {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Log.d("ERR", "connected by jsoup");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

by the way, i am a newbie to android.Thank you

Comment: Can you show how you are implementing it with AsyncTask?

Comment: Can you also give us a stacktrace for when your application crashes?